# About Page on Windows 8 application

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

i'm trying to create a tab called about page under the setting in the charm(right bar). I want the tab About inside the settings and when clicked , it will load the information inside the snap view itself. I'm coding in C# , anyone have any idea about this?

Regards,
Binary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want an about link to show up when the user brings up the settings pane - and when clicked - that should show an about page in the settings pane itself - right?

If so, have a look at the [Callisto project on github](https://github.com/timheuer/Callisto): it has a SettingsFlyout which you could use as follows:

```
var settingsFlyout = new SettingsFlyout();
settingsFlyout.Content = new YourSettingsControl(); //this is just a regular XAML UserControl
settingsFlyout.IsOpen = true;
```

Now, all you need to do is execute the code above, when the user clicks on your settings link. As to how the link itself shows up in the settings pane, see the [App settings sample on MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-settings-sample-1f762f49).

Comment: Creating UserControls in Metro-style apps using XAML : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-user-and-custom-a8a9505e

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to register your About "page" as a SettingsCommand in order to get it to show up in the Settings charm.